# Debugging UWP app that includes desktop extension exe (Full trust process)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, uwp

I am looking for a way to hit breakpoints of my **console exe** that is launched from fulltrustprocesslauncher inside UWP packaging project.
I looked at the post below (which is from 2017), however, i am still not able to hit console exe breakpoints using visual studio 2019. When I set packaging project as startup project, I can only hit breakpoints for UWP app (**not console exe**).
[How to debug a .exe launched from Full​Trust​Process​Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086262/how-to-debug-a-exe-launched-from-fulltrustprocesslauncher)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-debug

So far I have been debugging my console app separately which is not helping debug communication issues between **UWP and console exe.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

When using UWP app as start project and starting console application (fulltrust) as "debug new instance", i cannot get App service connection to work.

```
        connection = new AppServiceConnection();
        connection.AppServiceName = "SampleInteropService";
        //connection.PackageFamilyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
        
    //i got PackageFamilyName by doing a console.WriteLine when i ran the app with package as start project
    connection.PackageFamilyName = "XXXXX - XXX - XXX - XXX - XXXXXXX";


        Console.WriteLine(connection.PackageFamilyName);


       
        connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
        connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;

        AppServiceConnectionStatus status = await connection.OpenAsync();
        if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
        {
    //FAILS here
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Something went wrong in initializing UWP connection from console side");
            
        }
```

Comment: Since the UWP app launch the exe file directly, you can not debug the console app meanwhile. If you want to debug the uwp app and console app, you could first launch the uwp app and then right-click your console app->Debug->Start new instance to launch your console app manually. After that, you could debug these two apps, but you do not need to launch the console.exe from uwp app during this process.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thanks for your reply. Do you mean instead of starting/debugging packaging project, i should start the UWP app and then console app-> debug->start new instance?

Comment: Yeap, you could try the above method to debug a solution that has several processes, for more details, you can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019#start-debugging-with-multiple-processes). If you choose "Start new instance" for your console app and set your uwp app as StartUp Project, can you debug them successfully?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I tired this solution. and I can hit breakpoints on console app however I am getting this error when I choose UWP app as start project instead of package as start project. **InvalidOperationException: The process has no package identity. **

Comment: It could not get the FamilyName when you run separately, for testing, you could set the PackageFamilyName property as the Package family name of UWP app manually to communicate.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Please see code above. i was not able to get App service connection started.I am getting AppServiceConnectionStatus==App service unavailable

Comment: Have you added fullTrustProcess and appService extensions in your manifest file of uwp? You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample) to test.